# Binding handlers to events in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, binding

I'm trying to bind some functions to an event.
The following code works perfectly fine in Chrome and FF but what's the corresponding code for IE?

```
$this.mouseenter(function(){ 
    console.log("inside the mouse enter handler");
});
```

I tried this but it didn't work in IE:

```
 $this.bind('mouseenter', function(){
        console.log("inside the mouse enter handler");
    });
```

I need it to work in at least IE 9.

Comment: Did you try passing an event with your function like this:

$this.bind('mouseenter', function(event){

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` or at least `console` will give you an error on IE... hence, your javascript will not work... try using `alert`...

Answer (score 0):

Unable to understand what is wrong @ your end.
I tried this and its working fine for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

console.log will return a js error, if your browser's console is not open. It will happen in any browser, not only with IE. Probably you tried FF and chrome with the browser console open and IE without opening the browser console. Try opening the browser console open in IE as well / by using alert() to test your funcitonality / by directly writing the functionality that you need.

Hope it helps!!!